# Sort Grid binded to ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper in ArcObjects 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#

I have a Datagridview which is binded to a ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper. So, I want it to be sorted when ColumnHeader is clicked. I tried to do the following on Click event:

```
ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper twapper = (ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper)((BindingSource)datagridview.DataSource).DataSource;
                ITableSort tsort = new TableSortClass();
                tsort.Table = (ITable)twapper.wrappedTable;
...
                string column_name = datagridview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
                tsort.Fields = column_name;
                tsort.set_Ascending(column_name, false);
                tsort.set_CaseSensitive(column_name, true);
                tsort.Sort(null);
...
                ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper tableWrapper = new ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper((ITable)tsort);


                tableWrapper.UseCVDomains = true;
                BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
                bindingSource1.DataSource = tableWrapper; 
                datagridview.DataSource = bindingSource1;

                datagridview.Refresh();
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect. Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sovled by rebuilding tableWrapper with this function.

```
public static void ItableSortToITable(ITableSort tableSort, ref ArcDataBinding.TableWrapper twapper)
    {
        List<IRow> rows = new List<IRow>();
        ICursor cursor = tableSort.Rows;
        IRow row = null;
         twapper.Clear();
        while ((row = cursor.NextRow()) != null)
        {
            rows.Add(row);
            twapper.Add(row);
        }

        return;
    }
```

If somepony knows a better solution will be highly appriciated.